# Payload performance in Lucene

Tags: performance, lucene, payload

I know there are several topics on the web, as well as on SO, regarding indexing and query performance within Lucene, but I have yet to find one that discusses whether or not (and if so, how much?) creating payloads will affect query performance...

Here's the scenario ...

Let's say I want to index a collection of documents (anywhere from 100K - 10M), and each document has a subsection that I want to be able to search separately (or perhaps rank higher, depending on whether a match was found within that section).

I'm considering adding a payload (during indexing) to any term that appears within that subsection, so I can efficiently make that determination at query-time.

Does anyone know of any performance issues related to using payloads, or even better, could you point me to any online documentation about this topic?

Thanks!

EDIT: I appreciate the alternative solutions to my scenario, but in case I do need to use payloads in the future, does anyone have any comments regarding the original question about query performance?

Comment: Have a look at Compass (http://www.compass-project.org/), it makes this sort of high-performance layering on top of Lucene a good deal easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I literally just came across Compass this afternoon, so it's good to know I might be on the right track. I'll try to report back if I have any luck!

Answer (score 1):

The textbook solution to what you want to do is index each original document as two fields: one for the full document, and the other for the subsection. You can boost the subsection field separately either during indexing or during retrieval.
Having said that, you can read about Lucene payloads here: [Getting Started with Payloads](http://lucidworks.com/blog/getting-started-with-payloads/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's what I'm currently doing, I just thought there might be a better way. Do you know of any references you could point me to that would support your claim?

Comment: You can try:
http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Optimizing-Findability-Lucene-and-Solr
and 
http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/

Answer (score 0):

Your use case doesn't fit well with the purpose of payloads -- it looks to me that any payload information would be redundant.

Payloads are attached to individual occurrences of terms in the document, not to document/term pairs. In order to store and access payloads, you have to use the offset of the term occurrence within the document. In your case, if you know the offset, you should be able to calculate which section the term occurrence is in, without using payload data.

The broader question is the effect of payloads on performance. My experience is that when properly used, the payload implementation takes up less space and is faster than whatever workaround I was previously using. The biggest impact on disk space will be wherever you currently use Field.setOmitTermFreqAndPositions(true) to reduce index size. You will need to include positions to use payloads, which potentially makes the index much larger.